# How to remove swap partitions from RAID 1 Array on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, raid, software-raid, swap, raid-1

Can anyone point in the right direction on how to remove SWAP out of a RAID1 configuration on Ubuntu 10.04 server? According to the Ubuntu Advanced installation guide, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/advanced-installation.html), it said to add swap to the raid but I am having some serious performance issues. I would like to remove it from the array and recreate it, with the same size, on the two separate drives. Zero data loss on the other array is a must.

It's a remote computer so I would prefer to do it via command line if possible.

Here is the output from `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
19530688 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb21 sda2[0]
957230016 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

Comment: Err... is the swap partition one of the md0 or md1 arrays?  What does ```swapon -s``` give you?

Comment: The swap device is md0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming /dev/md0 is your swap as it is the smaller of the two, you can just disable swap, stop the array, and delete it:

```
swapoff -a

mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --remove /dev/md0
```

Then you can just fdisk sdb1 and sda1 and change their type to 82 (swap).  Then `swapon -a` to activate. Change the fstab swap settings from `/dev/md0` to `/dev/sdb1` and duplicate the line for `/dev/sda1`.

None of this will impact `/dev/md1`.

Comment: Cool. Another question, do I need to do this by live cd or can I do it with a normal boot?

Comment: You can do all of this in a normal session.  The ```swapoff``` will reduce available "memory" - so if your physical ram is low this might impact running processes.  But in general this is a low risk operation.

Comment: Why not create them as RAID0 and get some performance out of it?

Comment: there is no need to RAID them. swap devices are striped by the kernel if they have equal priority.